# Function to check if url is valid

Tags: php, url

Well.. I want to check if the a url is valid.

So that they can not just enter things like `hoadw`, `adwij£1%`, but that the inserted url have to be a valid one like `domain.com`.

Was thinking of a function like this:

```
function checkurl($url) { 
   if ($url = "VALID") {  
      return true;  
   }else{  
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Look at the "Related" box in the sidebar. I'm sure at least one of those links will answer your question.

Comment: Do you want to check if its a `valid URL` or `URL exist` someone can still enter `http://www.dfsldskdskdsadlksdksd.com` which is valid but does not exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
function checkurl($url)
  //if it's valid it return's the URL else FALSE
  return filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
}
```

PS: you must be running PHP 5.2 or later.

Comment: Better, I'd say, to simply call `filter_var()` directly, rather than write a wrapper `checkurl()` method that does the same thing.